# Select only IDs where certain columns only contains a certain value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following,

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id          int,
  events      text, -- may be 'HR1', 'HR2', 'HR3', etc Or 'BP'
  event_value int
);
```

- `events` can be `HR1`/`HR2` (an `id` either has `HR1` or `HR2`, not both), or any other event: e.g. `BP)
- Every `id` has several rows.

I basically want to select IDs which have, for `HR1` or `HR2` (depending on which it is used for that ID), all their values in between 50 and 110.

The query for `HR1` or `HR2` returns a distinct `id` and `event` if all the groups values are between 50 and 110.

The following table is an example:

```
ID         |  event  | event value
-----------+---------+-------------
     1        'HR1'       80
     1        'HR1'       90
     1        'HR1'       72
     1        'HR1'       91
     1        'HR1'       69
     1        'BP'        2.3
-
     2        'HR1'       90
     2        'HR1'       40
     2        'HR1'       39
-
     3        'HR2'       200
     3        'HR2'       230
     3        'HR2'       85
-
     4        'HR2'       90
     4        'HR2'       80
     4        'HR2'       90
```

I want the following output:

```
subject_id  | event
------------+--------
     1        'HR1'
     4        'HR2'
```

Comment: This is very simple indeed, you are just saying find me those which doesn't have any values outside a range.

Comment: How many rows are you dealing with in your real problem?  what percentage of the table is `hr1` and `hr2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the desired output, which makes this a completely different request. You want one row per subject now, an aggregation:

```
SELECT id, event
FROM t
WHERE event in ('HR1', 'HR2')
GROUP BY id, event
HAVING count(CASE WHEN event_value NOT BETWEEN 50 AND 110 THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Many thanks!
Just an extra, imagining that I have an family_id and I would add it in the select and group by statement, would your code allow more than 1 family_id?

Comment: This is a lot of extra work, given an index on subject_id, and event you'd be better with an antijoin.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: I doubt that. It's running through the table once and a sort mainly. An anti join is a method used on young DBMS still weak on `NOT EXISTS`; in PostgreSQL you'd rather do the straight-forward `NOT EXISTS` instead, but then how to apply this here? Like in my other answer and then a final `DISTINCT`? That sounds more costly.

Comment: @Diogo Tec: `GROUP BY x, y` means "give me result one row per x/y pair". So if you include a `family_id` in `GROUP BY` you would get mutliple rows in case of multiple `family_id`. If you don't want this, then select the minimum or maximum instead (`min(family_id)` or `max(family_id)`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in this method, you're having to scan all `hr1`, `hr2`. Full stop that's slow. In the other method, you can either use an index on event_value to satisfy the whole query, or you can scan only until you find the first offending row. In both aggregation and DISTINCT you're having to order. However, in yours you're having to order **all** `hr1` and `hr2` and in the other you're only ordering a subset.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: With the sample data shown, I assume a full table scan to be the best approach anyway. Why go through an index tree only to end up with having to read 90% of the records? That would be way to slow.

Comment: If you're assuming that there are only 10 rows because the question has 10 rows, then ultimately it's going to be pretty hard to write anything *slow* in 2018, and nothing will ever use an index. However, I do prefer my queries to be able to use an index, if available, and if there are enough rows. ;)

Comment: @Evan Carroll: No, I'm not talking about ten rows, I'm talking of HR1/HR2 records accounting for 90% of the table. All these records have to be read.

Comment: No they don't all have to be read in either case. In the case where they're on the index, as I said you could do the whole thing with an index-only scan. In the case where they're not on the index, you would only have to find one violating copy for each subject/event to disqualify. In **your** query they're **all** read, the point here is that it needn't be the case.

Answer (score 2):

I would use  `NOT EXISTS` and `DISTINCT subject_id,event` to make it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,event  
FROM t AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM t AS t2
    WHERE (t2.event_value < 50 OR t2.event_value > 110)
        AND t1.id = t2.id
        AND t1.event = t2.event
)
AND t1.event in ('HR1','HR2');
```

Comment: I believe this works, but is slower than Thorsten's code!
Many thanks tho!

Comment: @DiogoTec You should have `t1.id = tt.id AND t1.event = tt.event` to do what you want. You should then find it substantially faster. (assuming you have an index on `(id,event)`)

Comment: @DiogoTec try that form.

Answer (score 2):

Thorsten's answer is fine, but I would express it as:

```
select subject_id,
       min(event) -- only one event per subject
from mytable
where event in ('HR1', 'HR2')
group by subject_id
having min(event_value) >= 50 and
       max(event_value) <= 110
order by subject_id;
```

Comment: Yes, using `min` and `max` in `having` is more readable. As to `min(event)`, I considered this, but then thought that if I grouped by `event`, too, instead, this would detect inconsistencies (i.e. show a subject twice in case it has both HR1 and HR2). But `min(event)` is a good solution. A matter of preference, whether the query shall assume consistency or better not rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is no longer valid, as the OP has altered the requirement.

<strike>No, this is not complex. You want to exclude subjects for which exist HR1/2 records with a value outside the given bounds. So use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`.</strike>

```
select *
from mytable
where subject_id not in
(
  select subject_id
  from mytable
  where event in ('HR1', 'HR2')
  and event_value not between 50 and 100
)
order by subject_id;
```

Comment: I have edited the expected output - my apologies. Can you help me?

Comment: I've added another answer, as this is a completely different task now.